# Check if value exists in group and assign it to all rows of group in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to check if the value `a` exists in each user id group and then assign this value to all rows of this user id/group. For example for the following data:

```
user_id type    
    123    a
    123    b
    234    c
```

I should get:

```
user_id type    
    123    a
    123    a
    234    c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  if(0 = countif(type = 'a') over(partition by user_id), type, 'a') as assigned_type,
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by executing a query similar to this:

```
UPDATE so_test.a_updates
SET type = 'a'
where user_id in (
  select user_id
  from `elzagales.so_test.a_updates`
  where type = 'a'
);
```

additionally if this is something you want to repeatedly do you can make this a stored procedure using a similar structure.